# SQL Script Component c# select statement only read once

Tags: c#, sql, select

I have a problem: I established a successful connection to another database (`dwh_fct_overgangen`) and I am using a select command to retrieve a max value from the other database. This runs perfectly well for the first row. However after the second row is selected (which contains a different value than the first row) it does not select the max value from the other database anymore.

Could it be that the parameter gets only the first time a particular value and this value never change when processing new rows?

Or is it possible that the SQL command is only executed once?

Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong

```
public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
{
    base.AcquireConnections(Transaction);
    connMgr = this.Connections.ConnectionDWH;
    conn = (SqlConnection)connMgr.AcquireConnection(null);
}

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
}


int volgnrteller = 0;
int materieelbuffer = 0;
int matcheck = 0;
string locatiebuffer = "";


public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{

    cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(volgnr) from dwh_dz.fct_Overgangen where dwh_dz.fct_Overgangen.Mat_nr= @matcheck)", conn);
    SqlParam = new SqlParameter("@matcheck", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
    SqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(SqlParam);


        if (materieelbuffer != Row.Matnr)
        {
            volgnrteller = 0;
            try
            {          
                cmd.Parameters["@matcheck"].Value = Row.Matnr;
                sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
                sqlReader.Read();
                volgnrteller = sqlReader.GetInt32(0);
                sqlReader.Close();
                materieelbuffer = Row.Matnr;
             }
            catch (Exception e)   
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                volgnrteller++;
                materieelbuffer = Row.Matnr;
            }

        }
        else if (locatiebuffer != Row.Locatie)
        {

            volgnrteller++;
            Output0Buffer.Tijduit = Row.TIJD;
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            in_tijdbuffer = Row.TIJD;
            locatiebuffer = Row.Locatie;
          }

}
```

Comment: You should start by checking your return values. You call `Read()` but never check for success. If you want to get a scalar value, maybe `ExecuteScalar` would be easier than a full blown reader.

Comment: I can only say that you have too much global variables at play here. Everyone of them could drive your code in the wrong direction on these cases. The best option here is to start the debugger and check the code flow and the values of your variables

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm just not seeing it, but it doesn't look like this method "Input0_ProcessInputRow" is executed more than once. I see no while statement or it being executed twice like you describe.

Are you trying to select multiple rows into a dataset, because SqlDataReader.GetInt32(0) is only going to give you the first column results.

Also the reader should be in a while loop, something like this.

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())   
{
    Q = int.Parse(reader["YourColumnName"]);
    txtbx.Text = reader["YourColumnName"].ToString(); 
}
```